# How do I get Mewtwo after I made it faint?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I accidentally made Mewtwo faint and it won't come back. I tried leaving and coming back, but it didn't work. How can I get it back so that I can catch it?

Comment: I already beat them....NOOO!!!!!!

Comment: You can fight the elite four as many times as you wish, just fly back to the end of Victory Road.

Answer (score 4):

To get another shot at capturing Mewtwo, you must beat the elite four (and champion) again. This will cause Mewtwo (and other similar legendaries you may have fainted rather than caught) to respawn.

As [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172438/is-it-possible-to-catch-mewtwo-more-than-once) notes, once you catch it, it will no longer respawn after beating the Elite Four.

Comment: Will this work each time? Example: If I KO'd him again, could you run the Elite 4 to attempt it again?

Comment: Yes, every time you beat the elite 4, stationary legendaries will respawn if they had been KO'd. To my knowledge, the only reason they will stop respawning after beating the elite 4 is if you caught them in a pokeball.

Answer (score 0):

REMEMBER THE RULE: before you fight and plan on catching a legendary pokemon, always save to to the nearest area so if you acidently kill them, you can just exit the game without saving and they wil be there again (and you don't have to run around the place)